# Why does SoftEther VPN listen to random ports? How do I make it stop?

Tags: vpn, port, softether

I have SoftEther VPN running on a Linux server with SSTP, L2TP over IPSec, VPN over DNS, and VPN over ICMP enabled, along with management via TCP port 5555.

I have disabled everything else I could find, specifically including SecureNAT and the server-assisted Dynamic DNS and KeepAlive functionalities.

However, when I run `sudo netstat -eptuwWl`, I see it listening to the following ports:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:5555                  *:*                     LISTEN      root       17326       6619/vpnserver
udp        0      0 *:domain                *:*                                 root       5273060     6619/vpnserver
udp        0      0 *:56432                 *:*                                 root       17850       6619/vpnserver
udp        0      0 *:42726                 *:*                                 root       17319       6619/vpnserver
udp        0      0 MY_ADDRESS:ipsec-nat-t  *:*                                 root       4493472     6619/vpnserver
udp        0      0 localhost:ipsec-nat-t   *:*                                 root       17376       6619/vpnserver
udp        0      0 MY_ADDRESS:isakmp       *:*                                 root       4493471     6619/vpnserver
udp        0      0 localhost:isakmp        *:*                                 root       17375       6619/vpnserver
udp        0      0 *:50676                 *:*                                 root       17309       6618/vpnserver
raw        0      0 *:icmp                  *:*                     7           root       5273062     6619/vpnserver
raw        0      0 MY_ADDRESS:esp          *:*                     7           root       4493473     6619/vpnserver
raw        0      0 localhost:esp           *:*                     7           root       17377       6619/vpnserver
raw        0      0 MY_ADDRESS:52           *:*                     7           root       4493474     6619/vpnserver
raw        0      0 localhost:52            *:*                     7           root       17378       6619/vpnserver
```

I can only account for the ICMP, ISAKMP, ESP, and IPSec-NAT-T, and 5555 listeners (that's 8 of them).
However, **I can't account for the other 6 listeners**. What are they for?

Comment: One (or maybe more) of those ports is used to list the Virtual Hubs on the SoftEther server when queried by the client.

Comment: @DRSDavidSoft: Oh wow, really? Is 5555 not used for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out 3 more of them myself:

- The one DNS (`domain`) socket is for the *VPN over DNS* functionality
- The two RAW (protocol 52 - "I-NLSP"?) sockets are for the *L2TP over IPsec* functionality

Disabling the options for reach of these removes the port listeners.

The bounty will go to anyone who can explain what the final 3 listening sockets are used for.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you add more listened TCP ports during the configuration?

SoftEther should listen for 443, 992 and 5555 by default.

Take a look [here](https://www.softether.org/4-docs/1-manual/3._SoftEther_VPN_Server_Manual/3.3_VPN_Server_Administration#3.3.6_Listener_Ports) and check for your config first.